# How to properly configure EC2 Instance for EBS Backed AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I've created an AMI from an Ubuntu EC2 instance, and have found a weird issue when attempting to connect to a newly launched instance from this AMI. When using the key pair that I chose to connect with, I'm unable to connect, however, I am able to use a keypair that was in the `authorized_keys` file when creating the instance. I've also noticed that when inspecting the `.ssh` directory there is another directory titled: `authorized_keys` with its full path being `~/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys`.

On the AMI I have also modified `/etc/sshd_config` to included `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` so I'm thinking this is related to this.

Here's the specific line in `sshd_config`:

`AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys`

An answer to this question would provide details on how to properly configure the `~/.ssh...` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` directories and configurations so that creating an AMI would work normally on any instance provisioned using the AMI.

Comment: Why did you make the change to `/etc/sshd_config`?  It seems pretty apparent why this breaks in exactly the way that it does, with that change in place.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I was planning on having a "Global" authorized_keys file to access all sshable users on the server. That way I don't have to go to each user's authorized_keys and add keys. I also don't see why that's apparent. Is the sshd_config read during provisioning such that it will create the authorized_keys files specified in the config?

Comment: Based on what you observe, it seems like there's no other explanation than that the config file is being read by the process that creates the authorized_keys file on first boot -- presumably, that's cloud-init -- and instead of overwriting the old one, it's creating a new one where it thinks you must want it.  I can't think of a reason why `AuthorizedKeysFile` would accept multiple arguments.  I also can't see how a global authorized_keys file would be useful, since it would make usernames meaningless... any user could use any key in the file.  Or did I overlook something, there?

Comment: Well looking at the docs I did find that you can have multiple arguments in there. It does actually work which is nice. The use case was something like shared hosting where you have multiple users. This gives you the ability to ssh in directly as that user without needing to ssh in as root first. I may try thinking of a different solution now as it does seem relatively pointless. All that to skip one step. Eventually I wanted to use the authorizedkeyscommand option to make an external request to get an authorized_keys files

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Well, after looking at the source of cloud-init it doesn't look like it's compatible with multiple `AuthorizedKeyFile` arguments. I think an alternative solution her would be to use the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` option that links to a short script that prints the contents of another authorized_keys file.